# Multiple SQL Queries that rely on each other

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run multiple SQL queries, all that rely on each other.

What I've got now doesn't work, so I'll show what I have now, and I'll explain what it needs to do.

```
SET @sub_cat_id = SELECT MAX(category_id) FROM exp_br_product_category WHERE product_id = '1234';
SET @prim_cat_id = SELECT parent_id FROM exp_br_category WHERE category_id = @sub_cat_id;
SET @prim_cat_title = SELECT url_title FROM exp_br_category WHERE category_id = @prim_cat_id; 
SET @sub_cat_title = SELECT url_title FROM exp_br_category WHERE category_id = @sub_cat_id;
$title1 = SELECT @prim_cat_title;
$title2 = SELECT @sub_cat_title;
```

The intended output should be that $title1 = maincat and $title2 = subcat. That way we can then build a URL from those two final variables.

I have researched on stackoverflow, but I cannot seem to find anything that is close to what I'm doing. Can someone please help me craft a query that will work properly?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**

The two tables are exp_br_product_category, which stores information on the products and their respective categories and exp_br_category, which stores all the category information from the site (including the parent ID of the categories and the url title).

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error message? Do you get the wrong values?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' The page throws a 500 error.

Comment: learn about joins http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: You reference two tables, `exp_br_product_category` and `exp_br_category`. Please explain what each one does.

Comment: What are you asking your web server to do when it throws a 500 error?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' I was trying to have it execute the query and it throws a 500 error, referencing the 1st line of code.

Comment: use PHP not MySQL for this things

Comment: Do you use phpMyAdmin to execute those queries? I think the SQL has notting to do with the Apache 500 error.

Comment: This is Apache error, not relevant with SQL And as xQbert said learn about joins

Answer (score 1):

This may be a better way to retrieve the data by making a join in the query, i.e., joining multiple tables in a single query:

```
SELECT
    prim_cat.url_title as prim_cat_title, sub_cat.url_title as sub_cat_title
FROM
    exp_br_product_category prod_cat,
    exp_br_category prim_cat,
    exp_br_category sub_cat
WHERE
    prod_cat.product_id = 1234 and
    prod_cat.category_id = sub_cat.category_id and
    prim_cat.category_id = sub_cat.parent_id
ORDER BY
    prod_cat.category_id desc
LIMIT 1
```

(Instead of using the max() aggregate function I've ordered the results in a descending order and limited the query to one result which should get the same result.)

Perhaps you may read something about joins [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins).

However, regardless of how queries are formed, it should not be the cause of a 500 error. It is most likely a webserver configuration error, maybe an error in your `.htaccess` file, or, less likely, with a specific PHP and webserver configuration, just a syntax error in your PHP file.

Comment: Thanks for this @pilsetnieks. I'm reading up on joins, but a quick question, how do I now declare a PHP variable from what is returned from this?

Comment: You cannot write SQL directly in PHP code, you need to somehow execute the SQL code and retrieve the values. Maybe you should start with something like this: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3599166/Connecting-and-prepared-statements-with-the-mysqli-extension.htm