# how to display all fields in mysql join statement if other does not have value

Tags: mysql

Below script is displaying only that data which they have on both table issuemail and amount. i want that all data should be displayed of table issue mail and amount will become o if that is not in amount table.......
cardnumber and barcode are unique in issue table and will not repeat...........on amount cardnumber may repeat but both cardnumber and barcode will not repeate together.......

```
Select issuemail.borrowernumber,
  issuemail.cardnumber,
  issuemail.firstname,
  issuemail.surname,
  issuemail.title,
  issuemail.author,
  issuemail.barcode,
  issuemail.issuedate,
  issuemail.date_due,
  amount.amount
From issuemail Inner Join
  amount On amount.cardnumber = issuemail.cardnumber And amount.barcode =
    issuemail.barcode
```

Comment: Do some research into join types, grouping, and the IFNULL function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Left Join instead..Like

```
    Select issuemail.borrowernumber,
    issuemail.cardnumber,
    issuemail.firstname,
    issuemail.surname,
    issuemail.title,
    issuemail.author,
    issuemail.barcode,
    issuemail.issuedate,
    issuemail.date_due,
    amount.amount
    From issuemail Left Join
    amount On amount.cardnumber = issuemail.cardnumber And amount.barcode =
    issuemail.barcode
```

Comment: Kindly Answer This pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192779/how-to-mail-all-order-details-row-in-a-single-mail