# Mysql full outer join 3 tables with group by and count

Tags: mysql

My query is only showing a subset of records of people who have messages for me whereas I want to return a list of all users wether  they have messages for me or not along with the count (or true/false, 0,1)

```
SELECT attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName, count(attendee_chat.to) 
from attendee_chat
INNER JOIN attendee ON attendee.id = attendee_chat.to
INNER JOIN chat ON attendee_chat.id = chat.attendee_chat_id
WHERE attendee.id <> 1
GROUP BY attendee_chat.to;
```

picture is worth a thousand words.

[image]

Comment: why is `WHERE attendee.id <> 1` there ?

Comment: I'm assuming he is attendee #1 and he doesn't want to count for himself I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the attendee table first in the FROM, and then left join to the other tables that may not have records.

```
SELECT attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName, count(attendee_chat.to) 
from attendee 
LEFT JOIN attendee_chat ON attendee_chat.to = attendee.id
LEFT JOIN chat ON attendee_chat.id = chat.attendee_chat_id
WHERE attendee.id <> 1
GROUP BY attendee_chat.to;
```

I would avoid doing a FULL OUTER JOIN as it is not necessary and may lead to some unexpected results.

EDIT: Try this.  Remove the `chat` table as you aren't selecting from it anyway, and group on the fields from the primary table `attendee`, rather than the on tables that may not contain any data.

```
SELECT attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName, count(attendee_chat.to) 
from attendee 
LEFT JOIN attendee_chat ON attendee_chat.to = attendee.id
WHERE attendee.id <> 1
GROUP BY attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName;
```

EDIT2: After discussion of requirements that he wants a count of chats that were to him (#1)

```
SELECT attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName, 
(SELECT count(1) FROM attendee_chat 
   WHERE attendee_chat.from = attendee.id and  attendee_chat.to = 1) as chatcount
 from attendee ;
```

EDIT3: After comment about external ID

```
SELECT attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName, attendee.attendee_id,
(SELECT count(1) FROM attendee_chat 
    INNER JOIN attendee a2 ON a2.id = attendee_chat.toid
    WHERE attendee_chat.fromid = attendee.id and a2.attendee_id = 123
) as chatcount
FROM attendee ;
```

P.S. I've changed from to fromid and to -> toid as it is dangerous using reserved words as object names ;-)  [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e189b/16)

Comment: ok, but then it's returning the same result set, I want list of all attendees even if they have no messages from me

Comment: awesome, question, why there are two more fields in the group by

Comment: Because quite often if you want to select the fields and you don't have an aggregate function on them, you have to include them in the GROUP BY clause.  Some version of SQL will throw an error if you don't.

Comment: I see, so if aggregate function like count is not present, having a single field in the group by throws an error, cool that you picked up that I wasn't selecting anything from chat table

Comment: Even if the count is present and you don't have MAX, MIN, COUNT, AVERAGE etc. around all the other fields that you are selecting and not in the GROUP BY clause, it will error in some versions of SQL.

Comment: could i use then just two fields instead of 3? I'm having some issues on my test records returned, not sure, am checking

Comment: I've added a picture, it's like list of attendees, and wanna display a number next to them, there's some problem with the results, I think we are confused with attendee_chat.to & attendee_chat.id for the join

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64748/discussion-between-dijkgraaf-and-user2727195).

Comment: another point that I didn't mention to not to confuse people, I've a 3rd party id integrated into the system, i.e. I don't receive primary key on the dynamic page, i receive and use 3rd party key to retrieve the primary key, I modified your answer and asking you while expecting if there's a better solution that I don't know of... `SELECT attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName, 
 (SELECT count(1) FROM attendee_chat 
 WHERE attendee_chat.from = attendee.id 
 AND attendee_chat.to = (SELECT id from attendee WHERE attendee_id = attendee.attendee_id)) as chat 
from attendee`

Comment: You can just select the external id in the list.

Comment: sorry didn't get you, can you please explain more, I nested another subquery to get the id

Comment: great, now using your example, if I say `attendee.id` is not known and we need to determine it from attendee.attendee_id passed (123, 456 or 789) and use it in the above query

Comment: Just add it as a where clause.

Comment: I added but it didn't work, can you please copy/paste and execute this in your fiddle to understand, `SELECT attendee.id, attendee.firstName, attendee.lastName,   (SELECT count(1) FROM attendee_chat   WHERE attendee_chat.from = attendee.id   AND attendee_chat.to = (SELECT id from attendee WHERE attendee_id = 123)) as chat  from attendee`

Comment: saw but not actually, please put 123 (only) inside the `IN` clause, 123 is actually me, imagine I don't know my `id`, i've to determine my id from 123 and then run the query, (think of 123 as 3rd party primary key, foreign key in attendee table)

Comment: cool, I see a2 alias, it's because the subquery sees the attendee table in the outer table

Comment: Yes, it would see the outer query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a join on records even if they have no matching element(s) in the other relation, you probably want an OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

[MySQL: Quick breakdown of the types of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins)

Comment: I did left outer join but same result