# Display products of sub-categories on parent category page in php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue in getting products on parent-category page. 
My database table structure:

Parent-category:

```
id -catname 
1 - Mobiles & Tablets
2 - Compuetrs
```

Sub-category:

```
id cid sub_name
1   1   Mobiles
2   1  Tablets
3   2  Desktops
4   2  Laptops
```

Products tables structure: My products tables are multiple and based on sub-categories. Example: Tablets products are found under **tablets** table and mobiles products are found under **mobiles** table. Products are stored under different tables based on their sub-categories.

```
id  cid  sub_id product_name
1   1      1     Lenovo latest mobile
2   2      3     Dell Monitor
```

Now i want to fetch products from tables(mobiles,tablets,desktops,laptops) on parent category pages. i tried this with union all but at a time only one table is fetching in query. Could anyone suggest something. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php  
if(isset($_GET)) {
    $cid = $_GET['id'];     
    if($cid == 1){ 
        $tablename = "mobiles"; 
    }
    if($cid == 2){ 
        $tablename = "computers"; 
    }
    $results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE cid = '$cid'");
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        // code 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Query in loop reduces performance, you can always join tables and get data by querying database only once,

Try,

```
SELECT products.product_name, parent_category.catname
FROM products
JOIN parent_category ON products.cid = parent_category.id
```

Joins also work on multiple tables, suppose you want to get category as well as sub category,

Try,

```
SELECT products.product_name, parent_category.catname, sub_category.sub_name
FROM products
JOIN parent_category ON products.cid = parent_category.id
JOIN sub_category ON products.sub_id = sub_category.id
```

More about joins: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins)

Comment: Thanks. But i need to fetch products from multiple tables that are related through parent-category id and sub-category Id. hows it possible through joins?

Comment: Thanks.. This means i can use variable name '$tablename' instead of 'products' tablename because i have multiple tables for products example: mobiles,tablets,monitors and list is going on......and i need to fetch data from thsese tables based on parent-categories and sub-categories

Comment: yes, and if you have same column names you can use union on those. @Sandeepsidhu

Comment: yes. i understand all but there is one problem.  if i want to fetch data on parent-category from two tables like mobiles and tablets having different sub-categories but same parent-category Mobiles & Tablets then query is working only for one table like if($cid == 1){ 
        $tablename = "mobiles"; } if ($cid == 1){ 
        $tablename = "tablets"; } them query is not qorking for tablets