# How to check if an ID exists in the result of a sub-query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following query to list the average value of a house people own:

```
SELECT PERSON.NAME, AVG
FROM PERSON, (
  SELECT HOUSE.PID AS PID, AVG(HOUSE.VALUE) as AVG
  FROM HOUSE
  GROUP BY PID
) HOUSES
WHERE PERSON.PID = HOUSES.PID OR PERSON.ID NOT IN (
  SELECT PID
  FROM HOUSE
)
```

The query does what I want it to do, except it doesn't include the people who don't have any houses, who should have "0" as their house cost average.

Is this possible, or am I way off?

Comment: Your query is basically an INNER join with another subquery, you need a left JOIN

Comment: Mihai's nailed it. But if you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Quick breakdown of the types of joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  For instance, in this case, you want a `LEFT JOIN`, but cannot express it.

```
SELECT p.NAME, AVG_VALUE
FROM PERSON p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT PID , AVG(VALUE) as AVG_VALUE
      FROM HOUSE
      GROUP BY PID
     ) h
     ON p.PID = h.PID;
```

If you want `0` instead of `NULL`, use `COALESCE(AVG_VALUE, 0) as AVG_VALUE` in the outer query.

Comment: While valid, using the same alias twice is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `left join`, that way records that appear in persons table and dont have corresponding records in houses table will grt nulls on the columns from houses