# get records from unrelated table in table2 based on value in table1 MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

```
       table1
        id
        name
        ownedby


       table2
        id
        ownername
```

Here, in table1, ownedby can be 0 (to mean it is not owned by anyone) or refers to id column of table2. Now what I want is to get data from table1 but get ownername from table2 if owenedby>0

The output basically is to be:

```
     1  0 ==>owned by no one
     2  Barka =======> owned by barka
```

Comment: What does id represents in table1?

Comment: you can use joins. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins

Comment: Hi @Harshil, it is an auto-number column. But the tables can't be related at all since many have no corresponding record in table 2.

Comment: thanks @TahaPaksu but the tables are not related so join operation won't work, would it?. And cross join seems an overkill

Comment: they seem related to me. table1.ownedby -> table2.id

Comment: tables are not related ? What do you mean? If in some cases the ID's are in both tables then you can left join.

Comment: Hey Taha, true but like I said, sometimes ownedby will be 0 when the record has no "owner" (i.e. public ppty concept). On other times, yes it will be ownedby=table2.id. If they were always related, i won't be struggling.

Comment: isn't this a trivial job for `left join` and `ifnull(t2.ownername, 'no one')`?

Answer (score 1):

Following query should work (though I didn't tested it):

```
select t1.id, t1.name,
(case when t1.ownedby = 0 then 'No one'
     else t2.ownername
     end) as Ownername
from table t1
Left Join table t2
on t1.ownedby = t2.id
group by t1.id;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Harshil...that is so close. Lemme tweak it a bit and if it works, will accept it as an aswer.

Comment: Sure... But if it's still not working, feel free to comment the issue here.