# How to get all the rows of a table who's column value matches the rows of a select query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have a table called "people". I want to select all of the people that have a certain value in column "town". Then I want to select all the rows in a different table which have a value that exists in the previous selection.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Quick breakdown of the types of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Two options, both involve a sub-query...

1. Use an `EXISTS` clause

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM `a different table` dt
   WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM people p
     WHERE p.town = 'a certain value'
     AND p.value = dt.value -- you didn't specify column names
   )
   ```
2. Use an `IN` clause

   ```sql
   SELECT * from `a different table` dt
   WHERE dt.value IN (
     SELECT p.value FROM people p
     WHERE p.town = 'a certain value'
   )
   ```

Personally, I'd go with the first option but depending on your table types and indexes, you should run some explain-plans to see which is more performant.