# MySQL between dates selecting Null values

Tags: mysql

I have an Sp to select some values from a table and there is a left outer join, and the condition of the join is to select with respect to from and to dates.

I need to select data b/w these two dates.

this is how the part looks like

```
SELECT *// all the needed columns
 FROM  mytable            
     //other joins   
     LEFT OUTER JOIN myview ON              
        //some conditions         
        myview .soldDate between @fromdate and @todate
```

The selection works fine, it selecting only data b/w those dates, but also selcting null dates.

[image]

How do I avoid selecting these null values?

Comment: Change LEFT to INNER.

Comment: better lose `OUTER` as well or you'll end up with `INNER OUTER JOIN` :-)

Comment: btw - in your question you *say* you have an INNER join but your sql uses a LEFT join which is why you get null rows. I'd recommend brushing up on the different join types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins

Comment: I am sorry with the confusion, I tried with inner join, then  I get the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to let condition in `where` instead of `on`, because you are using `outer join`

```
SELECT *// all the needed columns
 FROM  mytable            
     //other joins   
     LEFT OUTER JOIN myview ON              
        //some conditions         
WHERE 
    myview.soldDate between @fromdate and @todate
```

Or just use  `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: What would be the join condition for the left join?

Comment: From the result set shown, we can't be sure that `soldDate` is `NULL` because of JOIN or by design.

Comment: I added the condition in where and it worked, but changing into INNER JOIN not worked

Answer (score 0):

Exclude rows in join that does does not have a `soldDate`

```
SELECT * -- all the needed columns
FROM mytable
--other joins
LEFT OUTER JOIN myview ON -- conditions
        (myview.soldDate IS NOT NULL AND myview.soldDate between @fromdate and @todate
```

Your question doesn't explain why `soldDate` is `NULL`. It could be because of `LEFT JOIN`, but also by design.

If it's the first, just use a INNER JOIN. If it's by design, use my query above.

Comment: If no date is selected in the previous form, soldDate  is saved as null in the table.