# 2 SQL get from db

Tags: php, sql

a have small problem with my script.

I have data on database.
But I need to use the data from one table in the same table. And I do not know how to make it exactly to make it work I tried I created some features but they wrote it to me.

```
$sql = "SELECT header,text,user_id FROM posts";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
 <? echo $row["text"]; ?>

}
}
```

This code work 
But when I put it again in it to find out the name of the user so it does not

```
$sql = "SELECT header,text,user_id FROM posts";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
 <? echo $row["text"]; ?>


 $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$row["user_id"]'";
  $result = $con->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     <? echo $row["name"]; ?>
   } 
  }    
}
}
```

This not working..I d know how fixed.

Tutorials how to do it better will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should read about prepared statements, which gets around most of the problems you are currently having.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to join the table within the first statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT header,text,user_id,name FROM posts p LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
    echo $row["text"];
  }
}
```

You should also learn something about [Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins).
And as @TimBiegeleisen stated out use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/134138)

Answer (score 0):

I try this and not work to..

```
$sql = "SELECT id,header,text,author,u.username as autorname FROM posts p LEFT JOIN users u ON u.username = p.author";
$result = $con->query($sql);



<? echo "" . $row["autorname"]. ""?>
```

any Data is not show

Comment: Why are you trying to join the tables on the username when you stated in your question that you dont't know the name? Please edit your question and add the structure of your db tables `posts` and `users`.