# Null received on sql statement

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to get company items using an `SQL` statement which uses three tables and 1 `WHERE` entry on a local `XAMPP` server. I cannot figure out why I'm receiving `null` entries. I have given the database details below. Thanks

SQL statement:

```
SELECT company_item.id, item_type, name, COUNT(item_demand.id_item), COUNT(item_sold.id_item) 
FROM company_item 
JOIN item_demand ON company_item.id = item_demand.id_item 
JOIN item_sold ON company_item.id = item_sold.id_item 
WHERE company_item.id_company="fhajdkadas";
```

`OUTPUT:`

[image]

`TABLE: company_item:` for now it only contains 1 company item and all the values have been correctly entered, I have checked.

[image]

`TABLE: item_demand:` for now this table does not have any record and I think it should not affect the `SQL` statement.

[image]

`TABLE: item_sold:` for now this table also does not have any record and I think it should not affect the `SQL` statement.

[image]

Comment: You need to use outer joins to the tables with no records; unqualified, `JOIN` means an inner join.

Comment: What database are you using? But what I can tell you is that you have to change the JOINS for OUTER JOINS

Comment: Yeah I changed the JOINS to LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no data in your `item_demand` and `item_sold` tables, when you attempt to `JOIN` them to the `company_item` table it results in you getting no results. You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead as that will return data from the `company_item` table even when there is no data in either of the `item_*` tables.

```
SELECT company_item.id, item_type, name, COUNT(item_demand.id_item), COUNT(item_sold.id_item) 
FROM company_item 
LEFT JOIN item_demand ON company_item.id = item_demand.id_item 
LEFT JOIN item_sold ON company_item.id = item_sold.id_item 
WHERE company_item.id_company="fhajdkadas";
```

Comment: This Q&A is worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins